# Need help on reduce part in RXSwift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mvvm, system.reactive

I don't know how to fix below code.
I merged two separate publish subject and I want bind result to my `Tableview`.

```
    Observable.merge(myCardsViewModel.digitalCard.asObservable()
        .map { $0.map { item in MergeCardModel.init(bankId: item.bankId, cardNumber: item.cardNumber, holderName: item.holderName, id: item.id, isDigital: item.isDigital, status: item.status, expirationDate: "", expirationMonth: "", expirationYear: "")}
    }, card2CardMyCardsViewModel.mycardsItem.asObservable()
        .map { $0.map { item in MergeCardModel.init(bankId: item.bankId, cardNumber: item.cardNumber, holderName: item.holderName, id: "", isDigital: false, status: "", expirationDate: item.expirationDate, expirationMonth: item.expirationMonth, expirationYear: item.expirationYear) }})
        .reduce([], accumulator: +)
        .bind(to: tblView.rx.items) {(tv, row, item) -> UITableViewCell in
            

            
            return cell
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your binding to TableView using **RxDataSource**. In my opinion this thing the Best.

I send to you code, it used Collection View, but in Rx for table view it will be same implementation.

*https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources*

Here is Example:

**ViewModel:**

```
extension ModelListViewModel {
    enum Sections: SectionModelType, Equatable {
        static func == (lhs: ModelListViewModel.Sections, rhs: ModelListViewModel.Sections) -> Bool {
            switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (.model(let lItem), .model(let rItem)):
                return lItem == rItem
            }
        }
        
        typealias Item = Asset
        
        case model(models: [Item])
        
        var items: [Item]  {
            switch self {
            case .model(let models):
                return models
            }
        }
        
        init(original: Sections, items: [Item]) {
            self = original
        }
    }
}

class ModelListViewModel {
    //inputs
    let didLoad = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let modelSelected = PublishSubject<Asset>()
    //outputs
    let sections: Driver<[Sections]>
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private static var data: [ModelDTO] = {
        var array = [ModelDTO]()
        let firstModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.seatModel(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "seat"), modelName: "Seat")
        let secondModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.big_910_Model(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "910_big"), modelName: "Big_910")
        let thirdModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.big_730_Model(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "730_big"), modelName: "Big_730")
        let fourthModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.small_730_Model(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "910_small"), modelName: "Small_730")
        let fifthModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.normal_730_Model(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "910_normal"), modelName: "Normal_730")
        let sixthModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.butcherSmallModel(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "butcher_small"), modelName: "Butcher_Small")
        let seventhModel = ModelDTO(url: ModelDTO.butcherBigModel(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "butcher_big"), modelName: "Butcher_Big")
        return [firstModel, secondModel, thirdModel, fourthModel, fifthModel, sixthModel, seventhModel]
    }()
    
    init(context: ARRouter.ModelListContext, modelsEntity: ModelsEntity) {
        //TODO: Make sections due to responce from BackEnd
        sections = didLoad
            .mapTo([Sections.model(models: ModelListViewModel.data)])
            .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())
        
        modelSelected.map { $0.model.url }
            .unwrap()
            .bind(to: context.modelSelectedIn)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

and **ViewController**:

```
class ModelListViewController: BaseViewController {
    private struct Cells {
        static let modelListCell = ReusableCell<ModelListCell>(nibName: "ModelListCell")
    }
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
        didSet {
            collectionView.register(Cells.modelListCell)
            
            viewModel.sections
                .drive(collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

            collectionView.rx
                .modelSelected(Asset.self)
                .bind(to: viewModel.modelSelected)
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
    }

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let viewModel: ModelListViewModel
    private let dataSource: RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource<ModelListViewModel.Sections>
    
    init(viewModel: ModelListViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.dataSource = .init(configureCell: { (_, tableView, indexPath, item) -> UICollectionViewCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeue(Cells.modelListCell, for: indexPath)
            cell.setupCell(with: item)
            return cell
        })
        super.init(nibName: "ModelListViewController", bundle: nil)
        
        rx.viewDidLoad
            .bind(to: viewModel.didLoad)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        title = "Models"
    }
}
```

I send to you good example how to use it :)

Enjoy.

Comment: I solved this problem with combineLatest instead of merge and it worked.Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: Can we communicate outside of here? @Oleksandr Vaker